# One rock gameobject drops FPS heavily!

Tags: unity, textures, level-of-detail

Okay so this is really odd I have a game object (a rock) that even though is really high detail drops my fps from around 70 steady to 12!

Now the object is divided into LOD's and the closer I get to the object the worse it gets!

I have created a Material for each LOD of the object where i replace the normal map with a lower LOD (The other channels stay the same).

The import settings for the different LODS looks like this:

[image]

Now as of the textures they are set to 2k (all of them)

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

The object itself looks like this inside the game:

[image]

Even my scene view has framerate issues when looking at it.

Comment: Is the rock really high poly? The problem might be due to that

Comment: I see you have a mesh collider on that rock. Could it be bogging things down by trying to do physics calculations using the high detail mesh? Do your numbers change if you remove the collider, as a test?